# Is there a way to use styled components for ANT notifications?

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I'm still learning the interactions between antdesign and styled-components, and I have a question:

I know I'm able to pass the styles for components like the popover (which accepts the "overlayClassName" prop) doing something like this:

```
const styledPopover = ({ className, ...props }) => (<ANTPopover {...props} overlayClassName={className} />);
styledPopover.propTypes = {
   className: PropTypes.string,
};
export const Popover = styled(styledPopover)`...`
```

But for the notifications, I have the className prop, but there's no component to style, just a function.

https://ant.design/components/notification/

Is there a way to wrap it into a styled component?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I managed to make it work the way I wanted through the "createGlobalStyle" method in the styled-components API. But I'm not happy with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to style the Antd Notification is using the `style` config from the [API](https://ant.design/components/notification/#API)

> style:    Customized inline style ->  CSSProperties

Here is an simple example [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-http-7oqet?file=/index.js).

---

To use antd together with styledComponents you can override `getContainer` which returns by default `document.body`. Thats why your `createGlobalStyle` approach works.

Here you can return a `ref` to your trigger e.g. to a `Button`.

`getContainer: (triggerNode) => buttonRef.current`

Note: With this the correct style is choosen, but the whole Notification seems to be broken (test the cancel button).

Full code example from [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-jang-k9rss?file=/index.js:0-1150).

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Button, notification } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Styled = styled.div`
  .ant-notification-notice {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;

const Notification = () => {
  const openNotification = () => {
    notification.open({
      message: "Notification Title",
      duration: 20,
      description:
        "This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification.",
      onClick: () => {
        console.log("Notification Clicked!");
      },
      getContainer: (triggerNode) => {
        console.log(triggerNode);
        console.log(buttonRef);
        // return document.body;
        return buttonRef.current;
      }
    });
  };

  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Styled>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={openNotification} ref={buttonRef}>
        Open the notification box
      </Button>
    </Styled>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Notification />, document.getElementById("container"));
```